# While developing the resume in Overleaf LaTeX -Argument of \hyper@n@rmalise has an extra }

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am completely new in LaTeX, and while building my resume got stuck on this error, which I can't seem to get rid of.
The error that keeps bugging me is:**Argument of \hyper@n@rmalise has an extra }.***
I already tried changing TeX live version and still it won't work.
Not only that, but I can't use URL, as it won't be hidden.
The code is below:

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author
% License : MIT
%------------------------

%---- Required Packages and Functions ----

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\setlength{\multicolsep}{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\geometry{left=1.4cm, top=0.8cm, right=1.2cm, bottom=1cm}
% Adjust margins
%\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.5in}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset{
    frame code={}
    center title,
    left=0pt,
    right=0pt,
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    colback=gray!20,
    colframe=white,
    width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
    enlarge left by=-2mm,
    boxsep=4pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-7pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item{
    \textbf{#1}{\hspace{0.5mm}#2 \vspace{-0.5mm}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumePOR}[3]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1}\hspace{0.3mm}#2 & \textit{\small{#3}} 
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & \textit{\footnotesize{#4}} \\
        \textit{\footnotesize{#3}} &  \footnotesize{#2}\\
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2.4mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeProject}[4]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & \textit{\footnotesize{#3}} \\
        \footnotesize{\textit{#2}} & \footnotesize{#4}
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2.4mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}
% \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\vcenter{\hbox{\tiny$\bullet$}}$}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=0mm]}
\newcommand{\resumeHeadingSkillStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,itemsep=1.7mm, rightmargin=2ex]}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{justify}\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=3ex, rightmargin=2ex, noitemsep,labelsep=1.2mm,itemsep=0mm]\small}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{2mm}}
\newcommand{\resumeHeadingSkillEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\end{justify}\vspace{-2mm}}
\newcommand{\cvsection}[1]{%
\vspace{2mm}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    \textbf{\large #1}
\end{tcolorbox}
    \vspace{-4mm}
}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}%
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
%---- End of Packages and Functions ------

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% DEFINE ELEMENTS HERE %%%%%%%
\newcommand{\name}{Prashant Singh} % Your Name
\newcommand{\course}{Computer Science and Engineering} % Your Program
\newcommand{\roll}{xxxxxxx} % Your Roll No.
\newcommand{\phone}{xxxxxxxx} % Your Phone Number
\newcommand{\emaila}{prashantxxxxx@gmail.com} %Email 1

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont

%-----------PROJECTS-----------------
\section{\textbf{Personal Projects}}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeProject
      {Web Based Facial Authentication(Liveness Detection)} %Project Name
      {A website based facial authentication system, implemented using a Chrome Extension.} %Project Name, Location Name
      \href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWMOatrqTYM}{LINK} %Event Dates

      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {Facilitating users' logins to websites without having to remember their credentials}
        \item {Used Live detection techniques to create high order security.}
        \item {Technology Used: Python, Reactjs, Bootstrap.}
    \resumeItemListEnd
    \vspace{-2mm}
    
    \resumeProject
      {Realtime Chat App} %Project Name
      {A react based web application which allow users to chat in real time. } %Project Name, Location Name
      {} %Event Dates

      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {Used Firebase Authentication(SDK) to facilitate authentication \& Cloud Firestore to store data.}
        \item {Technology Used: Reactjs, Firebase, Bootstrap, HTML.}
    \resumeItemListEnd
    \vspace{-2mm}

    \resumeProject
      {Covid-19 Tracker} %Project Name
      {Daily and weekly updated statistics tracking the number of COVID-19 cases, recovered, and deaths.} %Project Name, Location Name
      {} %Event Dates

      \resumeItemListStart
        \item {Tracking world-wide cases using google maps and live API stats and datasets.}
        \item {Technology Used : JavaScript , CSS, HTML, API.
}
    \resumeItemListEnd
      
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
\vspace{-8.5mm}



% %-----------Achievements-----------------
% \section{\textbf{Achievements}}
% \vspace{-0.4mm}
% \resumeSubHeadingListStart
% \resumePOR{Achievement } % Award
%     {description} % Event
%     {Event dates} %Event Year
    
% \resumePOR{Achievement } % Award
%     {description} % Event
%     {Event dates} %Event Year
% \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
% \vspace{-5mm}



%-------------------------------------------
\end{document}
```

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `\resumeProject` to have 4 argument, but you are only giving it 3 ones.

With 4 arguments it compiles:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\resumeProject}[4]{
\vspace{0.5mm}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{#1} & \textit{\footnotesize{#3}} \\
        \footnotesize{\textit{#2}} & \footnotesize{#4}
    \end{tabular*}
    \vspace{-2.4mm}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelsep=0mm]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{2mm}}

\begin{document}

\resumeSubHeadingListStart
    \resumeProject
      {Web Based Facial Authentication(Liveness Detection)} %Project Name
      {A website based facial authentication system, implemented using a Chrome Extension.} %Project Name, Location Name
      {\href{https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWMOatrqTYM}{LINK}}%Event Dates

\resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```